Fixing Python wordsearch diagonal highlighting issue
So, I was building this Python word search program, which searches through the X*X grid of letters and draws highlights over found words. It works fine for horizontal and vertical words, but I was having difficulty with diagonal ones, as you can see in this image:

It draws highlights over other words, too. I tried the bound box approach but haven't got the desired results.
So, can any of you help with this, please?
import random
import string
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def create_grid(words, shape='rectangle', size=10,sizer=5): #Sizer is and extra argument used just for rectangle,as it has dimensions(length and width) of different lengths
    if shape == 'rectangle':
        grid = create_rectangular_grid(size,sizer)
    elif shape == 'square':
        grid = create_rectangular_grid(size, size)  # Using same function for square as it's just a rectangle with equal dimesnions(length and width)
    elif shape == 'circle':
        grid = create_circular_grid(size)
    elif shape == 'heart':
        grid = create_heart_grid(size)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported shape. Choose 'rectangle', 'square', 'circle', or 'heart'.")
    
    for word in words:
        place_word(grid, word)
    
    fill_empty_spaces(grid)
    return grid


def create_rectangular_grid(width, height):
    return [[' ' for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]

def create_circular_grid(diameter):
    grid = [[None for _ in range(diameter)] for _ in range(diameter)]
    center = diameter // 2
    radius = diameter // 2
    for y in range(diameter):
        for x in range(diameter):
            if (x - center)**2 + (y - center)**2 <= radius**2:
                grid[y][x] = ' '
    return grid

def create_heart_grid(size):
    grid = [[None for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
    for y in range(size):
        for x in range(size):
            if in_heart(x, y, size):
                grid[y][x] = ' '
    return grid

def in_heart(x, y, size):
    # Heart curve formula
    x = (2 * x - size + 1) / size
    y = (2 * y - size + 1) / size
    return (x*x + y*y - 1)**3 - x*x * y*y*y <= 0

def place_word(grid, word):
    height, width = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    placed = False
    attempts = 0
    max_attempts = 100
    
    while not placed and attempts < max_attempts:
        direction = random.choice(['horizontal', 'vertical', 'diagonal'])
        x, y = random.randint(0, width - 1), random.randint(0, height - 1)
        
        if can_place_word(grid, word, x, y, direction):
            do_place_word(grid, word, x, y, direction)
            placed = True
        
        attempts += 1
    
    if not placed:
        print(f"Failed to place word: {word}")

def can_place_word(grid, word, x, y, direction):
    height, width = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    if direction == 'horizontal' and x + len(word) <= width:
        return all(grid[y][x+i] in [' ', word[i]] for i in range(len(word)))
    elif direction == 'vertical' and y + len(word) <= height:
        return all(grid[y+i][x] in [' ', word[i]] for i in range(len(word)))
    elif direction == 'diagonal' and x + len(word) <= width and y + len(word) <= height:
        return all(grid[y+i][x+i] in [' ', word[i]] for i in range(len(word)))
    return False

def do_place_word(grid, word, x, y, direction):
    if direction == 'horizontal':
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            grid[y][x + i] = letter
    elif direction == 'vertical':
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            grid[y + i][x] = letter
    elif direction == 'diagonal':
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            grid[y + i][x + i] = letter

def fill_empty_spaces(grid):
    for row in grid:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] == ' ':
                row[i] = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)

def draw_grid(grid, words, cell_size=50, font_path='./robotob.ttf', output_file='word_search.png'): # Customise font
    height, width = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    img_size = (width * cell_size, height * cell_size)
    img = Image.new('RGB', img_size, color='white')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, int(cell_size * 0.7))

    # Draw the letters
    for y, row in enumerate(grid):
        for x, letter in enumerate(row):
            if letter is not None:
                draw.text((x * cell_size + cell_size/4, y * cell_size), letter, font=font, fill='black')

    # Highlight words with rounded rectangles and pass font
    for word in words:
        highlight_word(draw, grid, word, cell_size, font)

    img.save(output_file)


def highlight_word(draw, grid, word, cell_size, font):
    height, width = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            if grid[y][x] == word[0]:
                directions = [
                    (1, 0),   # horizontal
                    (0, 1),   # vertical
                    (1, 1),   # diagonal
                ]
                for dx, dy in directions:
                    if check_word(grid, word, x, y, dx, dy):
                        draw_highlight(draw, x, y, len(word), dx, dy, cell_size, font)


def check_word(grid, word, x, y, dx, dy):
    height, width = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    if not all(0 <= x + i*dx < width and 0 <= y + i*dy < height for i in range(len(word))):
        return False
    return all(grid[y + i*dy][x + i*dx] == letter for i, letter in enumerate(word))

def draw_highlight(draw, x, y, length, dx, dy, cell_size, font):
    padding = 5
    start = (x * cell_size - padding, y * cell_size - padding)
    end = ((x + dx * (length - 1)) * cell_size + cell_size + padding, 
           (y + dy * (length - 1)) * cell_size + cell_size + padding)
    
    # Draw a black filled rounded rectangle
    draw.rounded_rectangle([start, end], radius=15, fill='black')
    
    # Draw the word in white on top of the black rectangle
    for i in range(length):
        tx = (x + i * dx) * cell_size + cell_size / 4
        ty = (y + i * dy) * cell_size
        draw.text((tx, ty), grid[y + i * dy][x + i * dx], font=font, fill='white')



# Example usage for wordsearch
words = ['JANE', 'LUKAS', 'BOB']
grid = create_grid(words, shape='rectangle', size=15,sizer=10)  # Arguments can be modified with different parameteres,it will overwrite defualt parametres used above in the function
draw_grid(grid, words, output_file='bw_search.png')  # Generated imagefilename and path can be modified,by default it saves the image in the same folder

I was having issues with highlighting diagonal words in a word search program, so I would like someone to help me resolve this issue.

I have achieved using Vb6. In fact, this year I had planned to try Tkinter..

Are you relying on Python to do it for you or do you prefer to manually search for words?

Try moving some of the stuff outside the the loop into the loop in your draw_highlight function:
def draw_highlight(draw, x, y, length, dx, dy, cell_size, font):
    padding = 5
    for i in range(length):
        start_x = (x + i * dx) * cell_size
        start_y = (y + i * dy) * cell_size
        end_x = start_x + cell_size
        end_y = start_y + cell_size
        draw.rounded_rectangle([
            start_x - padding, start_y - padding, end_x + padding,
            end_y + padding
        ], radius=15, fill='black')
        draw.text((start_x + cell_size / 4, start_y),
                  grid[y + i * dy][x + i * dx],
                  font=font,
                  fill='white')

Example output bw_search.png with above function change:



Before
After









If you want a continuous highlight, since PIL doesn’t natively support rotated rectangles, you will instead need to draw a polygon that mimics the effect of a diagonal rectangle yourself.
Here's an example that only supports diagonals going downwards to the right (since your code only generates them right now) you might need to adjust the padding a little and modify the function to support other diagonals:
def draw_highlight(draw, x, y, length, dx, dy, cell_size, font):
    start_x = x * cell_size
    start_y = y * cell_size
    end_x = (x + dx * (length - 1)) * cell_size
    end_y = (y + dy * (length - 1)) * cell_size
    if dx == 1 and dy == 1:
        points = [
            (start_x - 5, start_y + 20),
            (start_x + cell_size - 20, start_y - 5),
            (end_x + cell_size + 5, end_y + cell_size - 20),
            (end_x + 20, end_y + cell_size + 5)
        ]
        draw.polygon(points, fill='black')
    else:
        padding = 5
        start_x -= padding
        start_y -= padding
        end_x += cell_size + padding
        end_y += cell_size + padding
        draw.rounded_rectangle([start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y], radius=15, fill='black')
    for i in range(length):
        letter_x = (x + i * dx) * cell_size + cell_size / 4
        letter_y = (y + i * dy) * cell_size
        draw.text((letter_x, letter_y), grid[y + i * dy][x + i * dx], font=font, fill='white')




Before
After










Thanks for your help, actually i tried the same and got exactly same results,but i want highlights to be single continous rounded rectangle over words and not like indidviudlal rounded sqaures over letters,so can you help with that ?

See updated answer.

Thank you so much. This works well for now, but I couldn't find many resources online for drawing rounded polygon using custom logic, can you please help with that, too?
